# How to disable floating headers in UITableView with UITableViewStylePlain? Xcode 9 - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a plain style UITableView and wanted to know if it is possible to prevent the section headers from floating?

I do not want to make my tableview grouped.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change that behavior of section headers in a plain style UITableView.

What you can do instead of using standard section headers is to add your own extra row at the top of each section and make it look like a standard section header if you want that same look.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by implementing below UIScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     let sectionHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 40
     if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= sectionHeaderHeight && 
        scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-
            scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0)
     } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= sectionHeaderHeight {
         scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0)
     }
 }
```

Change the sectionHeaderHeight value as per your header height and your table header will not stop while scrolling the tableview.